# Tensorflow v1.4: Layer.input not supported in Eager mode

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, eager

I understand that Eager mode is a new alpha feature on the nightly builds and that it is not perfect yet, but I do not know if there are any tf.keras workarounds for this problem.

The error `Layer.input not supported in Eager mode.` triggers on the block

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.layers.Dense(2, input_shape = (None, 1)))
model.add(tf.layers.Dense(units = 1))
model.compile(optimizer = "sgd", loss = "mean_squared_error")
```

I do not know anything about keras or the keras tensorflow API and I was wondering if there was a way to avoid `Layer.input` with keras techniques so as to stay within Eager mode. Following a tutorial in the tf.Eager docs I have confirmed that `model = tf.layers.Dense(1)` works but I don't know how to add another layer.

Any help is very much appreciated.

**EDIT**
As of tensorflow v1.10, keras is supported in eager mode.

Comment: Did you activate tensorflow eager mode by calling `tfe.enable_eager_execution()` before running this code block? Eager mode is disabled by default.

Comment: @scai Yes I did, I believe that whatever interface keras wants to use simply isn't supported yet. I am wondering what keras methods there are to avoid `Layer.input`

Comment: I believe this should be resolved now, as Eager now supports Keras Models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras `Model`s are not yet supported with eager execution, but Keras layers are. Which means that while you can't use `tf.keras.models.Sequential` yet, you could combine layers yourself. See [the user guide](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/g3doc/guide.md#using-keras-and-the-layers-api).

Hope that helps.